# let UITableView animate selection if user-initiated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a tableView with `allowsMultipleSelection` set to true. In a custom UITableViewCell subclass, I have overwritten `setSelected:animated`. This gets called when I select cells (by tapping), and also when I scroll, as cells are being reused. Now, I would expect that the use case of the `animated` parameter is so that selection can be animated for user interaction, and not be animated when the state simply changes due to cell reuse. However, `animated` is always passed as false, regardless of how this gets called. Is `animated` ever true when this is invoked by UIKit stuff?

Of course, I can explicitly distinguish between user interaction and cell reuse by (a) removing `allowsMultipleSelection`, (b) implementing `UITableViewDelegate`'s `didSelect` and `didDeselect` methods, and (c) calling `setSelected` with `animated: true` from both those methods. But that seems like duplicating a lot of native behaviour just to change a small detail; I could save a delegate implementation and let my code read more intuitively (at least to me) if I could somehow get the tableView to pass `animated: true` by default when selection or deselection is user-initiated. Is there any way to make tableViews do this?

EDIT: not to mention, explicitly calling `setSelected` from the `didSelect` and `didDeselect` delegate methods doesn't really work, because it is still *also* called by the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I´m assuming you are selecting the cell with

```
cell.isSelected = true
```

> The selection affects the appearance of labels, image, and background. When the selected state of a cell is set to true, it draws the background for selected cells with its title in white. The default value is false. If you set the selection state to true through this property, the transition to the new state appearance is not animated. For animated selected-state transitions, see the setSelected(_:animated:) method.

As you can see using isSelected has the animated transition with false by default.

Try this instead:

```
cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623263-isselected)

Comment: I am actually talking about what happens when a user taps on a cell. I run no code myself; the tap is detected by the tableView, and `setSelected` is called automatically with parameters that I seem to have no control over.

Comment: If I understood correctly you need to call super with the right parameters. Try this:  
   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)
    }

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I want to _use_ `animated` to decide whether my custom version of `setSelected` should perform an animation or not. So I want the tableView to call with `animated = true` when I tap a cell. I don't see how anything I change in my implementation of `setSelected` will influence the parameters it gets called with. Put it this way: `setSelected` is called automatically (not by me), but always called with `animated = false`. Can I do something so that it gets called with `animated = true` by the tableView (without calling it myself)?

Comment: Just to understand the context, do you want to have animated = true when a cell is selected and animated = false when unselected? This by default of your overrided setSelected, correct?

Comment: I want animated=true when I select or deselect a cell *by tapping it*, and I want animated=false when cells are being reused when scrolling.

Comment: As far as I know that´s not possible for the simple reason that when setSelected is called you can´t distinguish if it came from a user´s tap or from reusing a cell. You will need to use the tableView´s didSelect delegate method. Maybe someone else comes up with a solution...